# Where should I store likes and dislikes for videos?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'am building a video hosting site, and I want my users to be able to like or dislike the videos, the problem is that I have the users and the videos tables in MySQL, and I don't know where to store the likes or dislikes

Should I store them in the users table or the videos table, or make a new table and link it with the videos and the users?

Something like this:

```
id  |  video_id  | user_id  | like_or_dislike
1   |  2         | 4        | 0
2   |  2         | 5        | 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely a separate table. Storing likes for lots of videos in the users table or for lots of users in the videos table would be scaling in the wrong direction. You'd find yourself adding columns instead of rows.

Comment: Isn't this going to cause a problem, because the number of data is too much, let's say we have 10 videos, and each video has 1000 like, that's 10000 row for only ten videos !!

Comment: @zakaria Yes, if you have that many users, you could have that many rows in your "likes" table. But that's not that many rows for a database. Think about how you'd implement it using only the existing tables. If you only want to know how many likes a video got, you could easily just add a column to your videos table, but if you want to start making recommendations, you're going to want to know *who* liked *what* video.

Comment: @zakaria Properly indexed, MySQL can handle tables with billions of rows.

Comment: @ceejayoz Really! well, that's a relief.

Comment: +1 A `user` can like (or dislike) zero, one or more videos. And a `video` can be liked by zero, one or more users. (Or disliked. Haters gotta hate.) That's a classic many-to-many relationship between `user` and `video`.  Adding a table to resolve that relationship is the traditional relational approach. There can also be other information on the row. For example the date and time a user "liked" a video. And performance isn't likely to be a problem, as long as **appropriate indexes** are available, and queries are appropriately written.

Comment: does YouTube use MYSQL as well? think about the number of comments each video has, and the number of likes each comment has !!

Comment: @zakaria Yes, looks like they do. http://highscalability.com/youtube-architecture

Comment: "10,000 rows for only 10 videos" Sure, but as opposed to what? If you put a separate column in each video record for every user, or a column in the user record for every video, then not only would you be changing the database structure every time a new user or video was added, but each record would be huge. If you don't care about which user voted for each video, you could just store total likes, adding one every time there's another vote. But right away that would create the problem that you'd have no way to know if the user had already voted on this video.

Answer (score 2):

The second option is the best one, this is way more organized and easier to fetch data. The user table should only have user data. User actions should be in a separate table. Create the foreign keys for user_id and video_id and you can make `like_or_dislike` a `tinyint` since it's best for `booleans`.